# SSH Connection closed by remote host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have problem to connect with SSH to remote host but only on my home network (provider). If I am at another network (my friend in same city - different provider) the connection works perfect. Ping to the server (at my home) works. Also this problem I have only with this server. If I try connect to other host from my home network, it works. What should I do?

```
nich@ubuntu:/etc$ ssh -vvv xxx@www.sci.muni.cz
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to www.sci.muni.cz [147.251.24.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/nich/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nich/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nich/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nich/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nich/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nich/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

nich@ubuntu:/etc$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Comment: Could it be the remote side requests reverse-dns and drops the connection if unavailable ?

Comment: So I can't do anything?

Comment: Well, first establish this is the case (perhaps by looking in the logs on the remote server). If it *is* the case and you can't get the admin to drop this setting you can tunnel your connection or just ssh to an intermediary host and then ssh from there.

Comment: The connection to refusing host through another host is working. But I can't use that because I want to mount the server files to my local ubuntu (nautilus).

Comment: Can you tell me some more information about this solution?
If I want connect to xxx@www.sci.muni.cz how should the tunnel command look?

Comment: I tried this: ssh -vvv -f xxx@www.sci.muni.cz -L 2000:192.168.2.4:22 -N

, where 192.168.2.2 = my local IP address, but the situation is same

Comment: Did you try to ssh your server at home, from its private network IP address? I met the case this week: from my company network, I cannot connect to the public IP address of an internal server whereas it's private IP address works as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you can attempt to create a tunnel.

- `intermediary` is a machine you trust to do the forwarding for you
- `remote` is the machine you're trying to get to

  ```
  ssh -N -L 20000:remote:22 user@intermediary
  ```

Once you do this your local machine will listen on port 20000. When you **connect with ssh to this port**, on your host, the connection will be forwarded over the tunnel to `intermediary` who will in turn forward it to `remote`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061116/ssh-tunneling-for-sftp-or-gui

The answer with ~/.ssh/config file works and fix my problem.

Comment: @PetrPřikryl Agent forwarding, cool.