# ssh tunneling with Nautilus using .ssh/config

Tags: ssh, remote-server, ssh-tunnel, nautilus

I want to connect to a server with Nautilus on Ubuntu 18.4.04. 
This server needs a tunnel that is described in `.ssh/config` like this :

```
Host serveurA
    Hostname server_to_connect
    User myself
    ProxyCommand ssh myself@tunnel_server -W %h:%p
    ForwardX11 yes
    IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

This setting works well from terminal I can connect with `ssh serverA`, fine. Now I try to connect from Nautilus through `ssh://serverA` and `sftp://serverA` as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551068/13032783 and here https://smashingweb.info/connect-remote-server-nautilus-using-key-file-pem-file/, but it doesn't work and I can't understand why, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I figured this out, before trying to use "sftp://serverA" go to your command line and do this:

```
ssh-add /home/xekon/.ssh/pve
```

after doing that close any open nautilus windows and try it again. worked on my system. the weird thing is that the ssh key files are already defined in my ssh config so I can only assume that nautilus does not check or honor the identityfile line in the ssh config file.

```
nano ~/.ssh/config

host pve proxmox
  hostname 192.168.1.7
  identityfile ~/.ssh/pve
  user root
  port 22
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with plasma and it seemed to not be working for me either until I used the ssh-add command.

If I use dolphin instead then "sftp://serverA" works perfectly, however copying files to remote servers with dolphin is slow because it is not asynchronous yet. (files transfer at 35 MiB/s instead of 110) I found a suggestion to try nautilus for full network speed.